# Storing and parsing CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, parsing, codeigniter, escaping

I am trying to come up with a better way of storing/parsing CSS/JS content in my CMS.  Originally I guess the obvious choice to me was to store them in chunks to the database.

I have however opted to store them chunks in my filesystem so the can be easily cached amoung other things.

My questions is before I create these files are there any parsing/escaping issue's I may run into?

Advice on wrapping them etc is also welcome.

My CMS is built upon the Codeigniter framework with xss_filtering turned off so the data is pretty raw.

The input itself will come from an admin so my worry is he/she may post in some dodgy data without even knowing.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're letting an end-user edit CSS and JS... of course you'll run into parsing issues :).  You have to leave it raw if they're editing the source, which gives them the ability to screw it up.

File system is definitely the way to go.  You'll run into encoding issues if you're allowing unicode input (i.e. pasting in formatted `&quot;` marks or non-ascii characters).  You might strip out all non-ascii input.  Otherwise, should be fine.

Comment: Hey landons, thanks for the reply. Yeah as you say the end-user will have free rein over the content, my concern is the render stage. For example they might include script tags or doc ready events, I may want to remove those and write my own wrapper